# my update method is not calles from test class of vfpage

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

i want to cover this code but its not getting covered

```
    public Opportunity opp {get; set;}
    public boolean isSuccess{get;set;}

public PageReference doSave(){          
PageReference pr;
          if(opp.StageName == '17 - Renewal - 0 - Lost'){
                if(opp.Lost_Reasons__c == NULL || opp.Lost_Reason__c == NULL || opp.Competitor__c == NULL || opp.Other_Lost_Business_Reasons__c == NULL){
                      apexpages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.ERROR,'Please provide Lost Category, Lost Reason, Competitor & Specific Loss Details.'));  
                      return pr;  
                      system.debug('opportunity--->>' + opp);
                }
          }else{
              apexpages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.ERROR,'Stage Name should be 17 - Renewal - 0 - Lost'));  
              return pr;
          }

    List<Opportunity> listOfOpporunity = [select id,Name from Opportunity where AccountId =: opp.AccountId];
    if(!listOfOpporunity.isEmpty()){
        for(Opportunity o:listOfOpporunity){
            o.StageName =  opp.StageName;
            o.Lost_Reasons__c =  opp.Lost_Reasons__c;
            o.Lost_Reason__c =  opp.Lost_Reason__c;
            o.Competitor__c =  opp.Competitor__c;
            o.Other_Lost_Business_Reasons__c = opp.Other_Lost_Business_Reasons__c;
        }
        update listOfOpporunity;
        isSuccess = true;
```

and  i have tried this code for cover this and in actual i am not able to update the value from the vf page ,, i am getting please provide lost category msz, and i don't know how to write the pagemesssage in system.assert?

```
Opportunity objOpp = new Opportunity();
objOpp.StageName = '1 - Suspect - 10';
objOpp.Name = 'TESTOpp1';
objOpp.CloseDate = Date.today().addDays(30);
objOpp.Contract_Start_Date__c = Date.today().addMonths(-12);
objOpp.Billing_Cycle_Months__c = 12;
objOpp.Contract_Duration_Months__c = 9;
objOpp.NMRR__c = 5000;
objOpp.MRR__c = 6000;
objOpp.AccountId = objAccount.Id;
objOpp.RecordTypeId = rtypes2.id;
insert objopp;

Test.startTest();
    Test.setCurrentPage(Page.MarkRenewalLost);
    MarkRenewalLostController markrenew = new MarkRenewalLostController(new ApexPages.StandardController(objOpp));
    markrenew.isSuccess = false;
    markrenew.opp.StageName = '17 - Renewal - 0 - Lost';
    markrenew.opp.Lost_Reasons__c = 'Agreement Terms';
    markrenew.opp.Competitor__c = 'N/A';
    markrenew.opp.Other_Lost_Business_Reasons__c = 'this is';

    markrenew.doSave();
    markrenew.doCancel();
Test.stopTest();
System.debug('new updated---->>' + listopp);
```

Comment: *Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is **the most important part of unit testing**. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as **[smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests**.* -
 [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)

Comment: ya it is working as my expectation but my class is not covered.

Comment: You don't seem to have read a single word I wrote. Coverage is *not the primary goal of testing*. It is just a side effect of well written tests. Your test method above does not contain a single assertion. You are also trying to test too many things at once. Unit tests should be *atomic*, testing one use case for one method at a time.

Comment: It would help if you provided more context for your code here. Based on your test, I can assume that the code you're trying to test is part of a controller extension class, but as is, your code wouldn't compile if I tried to use it directly. Please [edit] your question to include the entirety of your controller extension. Adrian has already covered (no pun intended) the importance of assertions. The other part to that is that **you only get coverage for code that is executed**. It's hard to give targeted advice on how to execute a particular line of code if we don't know to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in my comment, you only get coverage for code that is executed.
Like Adrian mentioned in his comments, coverage is not the primary goal of a unit test, and it looks like the test code you've provided is attempting to do too much (and your tests are also not exercising as many potential situations as I would personally like).

With that in mind, let's dive into your code & test. I like to think of each unit test having 3 phases:

1. Setup
2. Execution
3. Verification

In your test code right now, you are doing some amount of setup. This encompasses the creation, population, and insertion of your test `Opportunity`, as well as declaring/instantiating your controller extension class and setting the `markrenew.opp` fields.

The 'execution' phase of your test consists of 2 lines:

```
markrenew.doSave();
markrenew.doCancel();
```

Typically, I would keep the execution phase to a single line (`markrenew.doSave()`). This is also where I would put `test.startTest()` and `test.stopTest()`. More often than not, the exact placement of start/stopTest() aren't *that* important, but wrapping your execution phase inside of start/stopTest() does allow you to capture details on how much of the various governor limits the code you're testing uses (which can become important when your codebase grows and starts to interact with more components).

There isn't anything technically wrong with having both `doSave()` and `doCancel()` in your execution phase...but it's also not technically a *unit* test if you're testing two or more *units*. Focusing on a single unit of code in a single unit test is good practice though (and makes isolating issues to specific sections of code easier/faster when a test fails).

You currently aren't performing phase 3 of a unit test, but we'll get back to that a bit later. For now, let's step trough what happens when you call `doSave()` in the test that you've provided.

The first section of code we come across is this:

```
PageReference pr;
if(opp.StageName == '17 - Renewal - 0 - Lost'){
    if(opp.Lost_Reasons__c == NULL || opp.Lost_Reason__c == NULL || opp.Competitor__c == NULL || opp.Other_Lost_Business_Reasons__c == NULL){
        apexpages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.ERROR,'Please provide Lost Category, Lost Reason, Competitor & Specific Loss Details.'));  
        return pr;  
        system.debug('opportunity--->>' + opp);
    }
}else{
    apexpages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.ERROR,'Stage Name should be 17 - Renewal - 0 - Lost'));  
    return pr;
}
```

Looking at the test setup that you do, the Opp's stageName is indeed `17 - Renewal - 0 - Lost`, so we enter the first if block.

Looking at the next if statement, `opp.Lost_Reasons__c == NULL` evaluates to false, `opp.Lost_Reason__c == NULL`, however, evaluates to true. This causes the if statement to short-circuit (i.e. the other conditions are not evaluated), and we enter this second if block.

You then add a page message that explains your error, and then return a null `PageReferece`, which will refresh your page and display the error message. The debug statement after the `return` is unreachable (execution of `doSave()` is halted immediately after you execute a return, before the next statement has a chance to execute). You should move this to be before your `return`, or remove it (since it would be impossible to execute, and therefore provides no benefit and is impossible to cover).

**In the case where this is what you intended to test**

If the purpose of this test was to test that you get an error message when you don't specify all 4 of `Opportunity.Lost_Reasons__c`, `Opportunity.Lost_Reason__c`, `Opportunity.Competitor__c`, and `Opportunity.Other_Lost_Business_Reasons__c`, then congratulations! your code behaved as expected, and you should move to phase 3 of your test (assert that the changes made to your `Opportunity` in your controller extension didn't get saved, and that you would see your expected error message).

An example of the code you would need to add to perform phase 3 of your unit test might be...

```
// Re-query the same opportunity that we initially set up.
// This is required to see if any of the changes made via the controller extension
//   were saved or not
Opportunity afterSave = [SELECT Id, StageName, LostReasons__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :objOpp.Id];

// assertEquals and assertNotEquals only require 2 parameters, but including the third
//   parameter (a string message that is included in the debug log when the assertion
//   fails) is a good idea.
// Giving a specific message here can really help narrow down what went wrong
//   (all assertions that we make _should_ end up passing).
System.assertEquals(objOpp.StageName, afterSave.StageName, 'Expected the stage name not to be changed');
System.assertEquals('1 - Suspect - 10', afterSave.StageName, 'The stage name for the Opp after saving is different than expected');
System.assertEquals(null, afterSave.LostReasons__c, 'We shouldn\'t have had any value in LostReasons__c after saving.');
// ...and more assertions like that

// Finding out whether or not your page message will be shown is a little less
//   straightforward.
// You can only get at the page messages through ApexPages.getMessages().
// This gives you a List of ApexPages.PageMessage.
// Since you're only adding one message, there should only be one (any more would
//   be an indication of something else going wrong).
System.assertEquals(1, ApexPages.getMessages().size(), 'Expected a single page message to be included as a result of running our code');
// When running similar tests myself, I like to verify at least part of the content
//   of the page message.
// String.contains(String substring) is useful for this
System.assertEquals(true, ApexPages.getMessages()[0].contains('Please provide Lost Category,', 'Resulting page message was different than expected');
```

**In the case where you wanted this test to save the data set via the controller extension**

In this case, there are two possibilities. Either the code you're testing is wrong, or the test setup that you performed was wrong/incomplete.

If you want to allow the opp to be saved when `LostReason__c` is not populated, then you should modify your code to remove that condition from your if statement. It's also possible that you may have meant to use `&&` instead of `||` in that if statement (so that you only get the error message when all of the fields are null as opposed to when any of the fields are null).

If you're certain that your code is correct, then you need to update your test setup so that the environment you provide to the code you're testing matches the conditions that would allow you to execute the code that you're trying to target. In this case, specifying `markrenew.opp.LostReason__c = 'some reason';` prior to calling `markrenew.doSave();` would be enough to avoid entering the if blocks that set an error message and return. You would make it to the following section of code in your SUT (system under test):

```
List<Opportunity> listOfOpporunity = [select id,Name from Opportunity where AccountId =: opp.AccountId];
    if(!listOfOpporunity.isEmpty()){
        for(Opportunity o:listOfOpporunity){
            o.StageName =  opp.StageName;
            o.Lost_Reasons__c =  opp.Lost_Reasons__c;
            o.Lost_Reason__c =  opp.Lost_Reason__c;
            o.Competitor__c =  opp.Competitor__c;
            o.Other_Lost_Business_Reasons__c = opp.Other_Lost_Business_Reasons__c;
        }
        update listOfOpporunity;
        isSuccess = true;
```

Since your setup does include at least one `Opportunity` with the specified `AccountId`, your query will return at least one row, you'll get into the for loop (therefore executing that code, and gaining coverage for it), update the opportunities, and return.

Your assertion phase in this situation would entail querying all opportunities that match the `AccountId` specified in `objOpp`, looping over them, and asserting that the fields values you set in your `doSave()` method are the ones you get when you query the `Opportunities` again.

**Regardless of what you intended your test to actually test**

This is only a single unit test, but if you stick to testing one situation per unit test, then there's no way you can test/cover all of your controller extension with this single test.

The way to handle this is *to make more unit tests, each covering a specific circumstance*. One test would test to make sure that your constructor behaves as expected (you could assert that the Id field of markrenew.Opp matches the Id of the `Opportunity` you pass into your controller extension). Another test would cover what happens when one of your loss/competitor fields is null. Yet another test would happen when your stageName isn't '17 -  Renewal - 0 - Lost'. Still another test would cover what happens when everything should work and your `Opportunities` do get updated.

Testing situations beyond the 'happy path' (every input is exactly as we expect, and there is nothing wrong that should happen), getting into the 'what if this happens' situations, gives a degree of confidence that your code is **robust** (that is it can handle various, and less than optimal, situations gracefully). Doing so also makes getting the coverage required for deployment a non-issue. If you test a sufficient number of situations, the code coverage will follow.

Comment: 1st of all thank you @Derek F for this article now i understand the value of system.assert and get that the opportunity that i update from the page  markrenew.opp.StageName = '17 - Renewal - 0 - Lost'; is not getting update but i want update so that my opportunity get closed and my vf page get updated, i am getting stauck...can you please help me?

Comment: @sonam I included a section on that already (search for _In the case where you wanted this test to save the data set via the controller extension_). The summary is that your test setup is incorrect, and you need to additionally set `markrenew.opp.LostReason__c` to some value (any value) to avoid getting into the `if` block that creates the `PageMessage` and returns.

Answer (score 0):

You have no where updated the Opp in your test class, I would advice you to write the update statement as in say:

```
objOpp.MRR__c = 7000;
update objOpp;
```

This ensures that update of Opportunity in Test Class calls your update part of the code.

Comment: no this is not calling my method, actually this update is done from the dosave() method...so its again not covering my class.